# Using Koa2 with Babel in Node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, koa2

I know I'm missing something here. I'm running node through babel and using koa2 on my server. Fairly new to this so not quite sure what I'm missing, as I've been referencing a lot of things online.

Versions: Node 6.4, babel-core 6.14.0, babel-polyfill": 6.13.0

Getting a fun error. Looks like a generator is not being produced somehow.

```
assert.js:89
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: app.use() requires a generator function
    at Application.app.use (/Users/administrator/Dropbox/Development/moonlite/moonlitewww/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:106:5)
```

Here's what I'm running off of:

Package.json

```
"start:dev": "node -r babel-core/register index.js",
```

.Babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-3"]
}
```

Index.js

```
require("babel-polyfill");
import nodeServer from "./web-server.js";
var config = {
  prod: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  serverPort: process.env.PORT || 3000
};
nodeServer(config);
```

web-server.js

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import koaRouter from 'koa-router';
import send from 'koa-send';
import serve from 'koa-serve';
import logger from 'koa-logger';

const router = koaRouter();
const app = new Koa();

export default (config) => {

  app.use(logger());
  app.use(serve(__dirname + '/client/build'));

  app.use(router.routes());
  app.use(router.allowedMethods());

  app.listen(config.serverPort, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port:' + config.serverPort);
  });

};
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob mistake on my part. I was merging the packages from another package.json file in, and somehow koa got reverted back to the 1.x branch. Was chasing a red haring thinking it was babel.

If you see a similar error double check your koa version, and upgrade to koa2 like so:

**`npm install koa@next --save`**

---

"NOW YOU KNOW, AND KNOWING IS HALF THE BATTLE..."